# Uploading File to a specific location in Amazon S3 Bucket using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to upload few files into Amazon S3. I am able to upload the file in my bucket. However, the file needs to be in my-bucket-name,Folder1/Folder2.

```
import boto3
from boto.s3.key import Key
session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
bucket_name = 'my-bucket-name'
prefix = 'Folder1/Folder2'
s3 = session.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
objs = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix)
```

I tried to upload into bucket using this code and succeeded:

```
s3.meta.client.upload_file('C:/hello.txt', bucket, 'hello.txt')
```

When I tried to upload the same file into specified Folder2 using this code the failed with error:

```
s3.meta.client.upload_file('C:/hello.txt', objs, 'hello.txt')

ERROR>>>
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid bucket name "s3.Bucket.objectsCollection(s3.Bucket(name='my-bucket-name'), s3.ObjectSummary)": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$"
```

So, how can I upload the file into my-bucket-name,Folder1/Folder2?

Answer (score 1):

> s3.meta.client.upload_file('C:/hello.txt', objs, 'hello.txt')

What's happening here is that the bucket argument to the `client.upload_file` needs to be the name of the bucket as a string

**For specific folder**

> upload_file('C:/hello.txt', bucket, 'Folder1/Folder2/hello.txt')

Comment: While doing it the way you suggested it, I got this particular error:

    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\handlers.py", line 219, in validate_bucket_name
    if VALID_BUCKET.search(bucket) is None:
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: I comment the upload code and tried to see the Bucket is working or not. Bucket is working erfectly fine, after adding this line. I'm getting this error.

Comment: @Sourav Can you provide screenshot of the code you tried and the error u received?